# Make Graph From firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, mpandroidchart

I am Saving data in firebase according to timestamp and send data 3 time or 4 time a day. Now i want to make graph for a month and getting data of that month by start at and end at by timestamp but i getting 3 or 4 records of one day . I want to add all multiple records of day as single record and make graph of that month. this is code i am using to get all recode

```
 Query query = refpetrol.child("Data").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startmonth).endAt(endmonth);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                Total_Liter=0;
                Total_Price=0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Total_Price=Total_Price+ ds.child("Price").getValue(float.class);
                    Total_Liter=Total_Liter+ ds.child("Petrol").getValue(float.class);
                    Sales.add(ds.child("Price").getValue(float.class));

                }
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        draw_graph();
                        Price_textview.setText(String.valueOf(Total_Price)+" Rs");
                        Liter_textview.setText(String.valueOf(Total_Liter)+" L");
                    }
                }, 200);


            } else {
                Total_Liter=0;
                Total_Price=0;
                Price_textview.setText(String.valueOf(Total_Price)+" Rs");
                Liter_textview.setText(String.valueOf(Total_Liter)+" L");
                chart.clear();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image]